# React—get supported Attributes by JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a little experimental app that should take user html/svg input and render that as React virtual DOM elements. Basically I have:

```
const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(<user input>);

const node = e => React.createElement(
  e.localName,
  [...e.attributes]
    .map(attr => attr.name)
    .reduce((props, name) => {

      //i need that test
      if (<name is a proper react attribute>) {
        props[name] = e.getAttribute(name);
      }

      return props;
    }, {}),
  [...e.children].map(child => node(child))
);
```

React is complaining about `Unknown props`, like `xlink:href` if the input is svg. So I need to filter out all that »unknown Props«. In Order to do that, it would be extremely helpful to have that list as JS Object.

What I would like to know/to would be something like that:

```
import { KnownProps } from 'react';

const testIfProperName = name => 
  KnownProps.hasOwnProperty(name);
```

to write the needed test.

Do such a list exist and if so, can I import it into my Program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [react-html-attributes](https://github.com/jackyho112/react-html-attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! But as it looks like, it does not include svg elements/attributes

Comment: THANKS! That's it!